# When to use "в" and when not to use?

Tags: словоупотребление

I'm learning Russian. In the tutorial they say:

> Витя дома

meaning

> Victor is at home

Also they say:

> Витя в Токио

Meaning

> Victor is in Tokyo

So why are they using в at one place and not using в at another place?

Comment: When Victor enters his house he says "I'm *home*!", "I'll be *upstairs*". In this sense the Russian phrase is similar to the English one. "Victor is *in Tokyo*", but "Victor is *overseas*".

Comment: Note that in English you are also using different prepositions: `at home` and `in Tokyo` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Дома` is "at house", `в доме` is "in the house" - this just should be memoized. There are no other such cases, since "дома" is quite special word in this aspect.

As a sidenote, there's also form `на дому` (and this is actually real example of locative) - it's about having some work-related practice at home, like "Врач принимает на дому".

Answer (score 9):

'**Дома**' is a locative adverb, much like e.g. '**наверху**' or '**внизу**', and, as such, does not require a preposition. Actually, in colloquial English, one can also say 'I'm home' to state the fact of arriving there, also making the word 'home' an adverb.

Comment: Spot on. Дома is different from в доме.